# UV Texture Map coordinates. Am I understanding this right?

Tags: dictionary, textures, coordinates

I've been following Rastertek's Direct X 11 tutorials and I'm hoping to make my own font index file.

Here's a snippet of the file given on the website:

```
32   0.0        0.0         0
33 ! 0.0        0.000976563 1
34 " 0.00195313 0.00488281  3
35 # 0.00585938 0.0136719   8
36 $ 0.0146484  0.0195313   5
37 % 0.0205078  0.0302734   10
38 & 0.03125    0.0390625   8
39 ' 0.0400391  0.0410156   1
40 ( 0.0419922  0.0449219   3
41 ) 0.0458984  0.0488281   3
42 * 0.0498047  0.0546875   5
```

I'm wondering how to calculate the left and right U coordinates.

My understanding of this is that the far left of the texture is 0.0 and the far right is 1.0, so, for example the hashtag symbol # starts at 0.00585938% of the width of the texture and finishes at 0.0136819% of the width of the texture.

Sorry if I've poorly explained this, and in retrospect I'm quite sure I'm wrong. I just remember reading somewhere that the far left is 0 and the far right is 1. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did some math and I was right to believe left is 0 and right is 1.

(textureWidth / 100) * (0.00585938 * 100) = 6.00...

and 6 along x axis is the beginning of the hashtag symbol on the texture map.

OK, sorry for posting pointless questions